# Action on multiple records using checkbox in django

Tags: django, forms, checkbox

My page returns multiple records and need to do some action on the records using checkbox.

Let me put it in this way. I will display all the records on my template with check box on every record. when I select checkbox option and click on some action button, id's of the selected records should pass to view and perform execute logic on the selected records.

Some thing similar what we do in phpmyadmin

[image: Selecting multiple checkboxes]

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started: http://www.djangofoo.com/93/request-post-get-multiple-values

If this form is only relevant for trusted users you can implement it pretty quickly using [`admin actions`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).

Comment: Thanks arie for the link. I will try it, its pretty much understandable

Comment: I have a question, what would be the url conf when we pass a list?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean ... Basically you have to create a pattern that you can use to pass the form data to your view function. Hopefully this more detailed example will help you get an idea of the whole process: http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/blog2.html#comment-deletion